# Get single column results as a list from a stored procedure using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is my code I'm trying to get the list of `Equipment` from a stored procedure and the code scenario is very different than others as I can't make it work.

I've tried many ways as one can see in the given code but nothing works

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var model = new ViewModels()
        {
            ModelEquipmentRequestResult = new List<EquipmentRequest_Result>()
            {
                new EquipmentRequest_Result()
                {
                   EquipmentName = db.EquipmentRequest().ToList().ToString()
          //         (from a in new db.EquipmentRequest

          //select new EquipmentRequest { a.EquipmentName}).ToList();
                   // ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<EquipmentRequest_Result>("EquipmentRequest").ToList().TooString()
                   //db.EquipmentRequest().AsQueryable<EquipmentRequest_Result>(),

                   //custq.AsEnumerable()
                   //   .Select(o => new EquipmentRequest_Result() {
                                      // EquipmentName = o.EquipmentName
                      //}).ToList()

                }
            },
            ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel = new EquipmentSpViewModel()
        };
        ViewBag.project = db.PMSProjects.ToList();

        return View(model);
}
```

**This** line of code

```
EquipmentName = db.EquipmentRequest().ToList().ToString()
```

returns something like this:

```
EquipmentName   
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectManagementSystem.EntityDataModel.EquipmentRequest_Result]
```

Here is the stored procedure query:

```
SELECT 
    e.EquipmentName, 
    NULL AS Id, 
    NULL AS EquipmentRequestId, 
    NULL AS EquipmentId, 
    NULL AS Planned, 
    NULL AS Actual, 
    NULL AS Remarks 
FROM 
    PECEquipment AS e
```

Here is the view with which I bind this

```
@model ProjectManagementSystem.ViewModel.ViewModels

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestPartail</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ModelEquipmentRequestResult.Count; i++)
        {
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].EquipmentName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].EquipmentName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].Planned)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].Planned)
            </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].Actual)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ModelEquipmentRequestResult[i].Actual)
    </div>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your stored procedure.

Comment: Are you planning to serialize this?

Comment: @PiyushKhatri please check now

Comment: @Oluwafemi so far not

Comment: What output do you expect from your query?

Comment: What do you get running this `db.EquipmentRequest().ToList()`?

Comment: @TamasIonut list of all the equipmentNames nothing more

Comment: @Oluwafemi 
EquipmentName System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ProjectManagementSystem.EntityDataModel.EquipmentRequest_Result]

Comment: Without the `ToString()`

Comment: @Oluwafemi with tostring

Comment: You can't get the same result. This `db.EquipmentRequest().ToList()` should return something else.

Comment: @Oluwafemi it returns this http://prntscr.com/adw0xc

Comment: Can you clarify the question title please.  "get *single* column" but your view has **3 columns**.

Comment: Why are you adding `.ToString()` to a list?  that will just tell you the type of the list, which your various screenshots show/confirm.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes View has three but I just want to display one as you can see rest are editable

Comment: So your viewmodel has all three, but you only want one populated?

Comment: @freedomn-m becuase If I don't add it just goes red, as the answer given blow they work perfect in simple cases but here EquipmentName is also a column and I'm binding the list to it and I can not take a var inside this model, apparent no one saw the code and jumped into the answer

Comment: @freedomn-m and SP is basically returning 8 or 9 columns I just need to display one rest not

Comment: If you add `.ToString()`, you're converting the entire list of objects/values into a **single** string (not a list of strings, one for each, a single string).  That won't be of any use to you (in any scenario).  In this case, you've not told it how to convert the list into a string, so the default behaviour of .ToString() is to show you the type, which it is doing.

Comment: @TamasIonut answer worked so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<EquipmentRequest_Result> output = db
      .EquipmentRequest()
      .Select(x=> new EquipmentRequest_Result { EquipmentName = x.EquipmentName })
      .ToList()
```

---

**EDIT:** Specifically for this question's scenario

```
var model = new ViewModels()
            {
                ModelEquipmentRequestResult = db
                    .EquipmentRequest()
                    .Select(x=> new EquipmentRequest_Result { EquipmentName = x.EquipmentName })
                    .ToList(),
                ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel = new EquipmentSpViewModel()
            };
return View(model);
```

Comment: This will get the EquipmentNames from all EquipmentRequest table as a list.

Comment: EquipmentRequest  is not table its an SP

Comment: Updated answer now

Comment: My dear friend as you can see the code in question I can not use a variable in it I'd to bind this list with the column name inside a var model, your code is perfect when I'm not in this scenario

Comment: where can I put this code in the actionresult? please

Comment: This isn't related to this question. Please put another question of this matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106014/discussion-between-tamas-ionut-and-user3515453).

Comment: Thanks Tamas Lonut I love you It worked so far atleast  hope it returns the value too

Comment: Yes I did actually placed it their after posting that comment and It worked Fine Thank you Once again

Comment: Well as you wish :) I'm still going to mark you up :) as it was help full and thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

Upon clarification:

```
var model = new ViewModels()
    {
        ModelEquipmentRequestResult = db.EquipmentRequest().Select(result => new EquipmentRequest_Result
        {
               EquipmentName = r.EquipmentName,
               Planned = r.Planned, //replace with DB column name
               Actual = r.Actual //replace with DB column name
        }).ToList(),
        ModeleEquipmentSpViewModel = new EquipmentSpViewModel()
    };
```

The answer above does the same thing.

Comment: sort of like that but then its EquipmentName is also column name in that storeprocedure and it will be binded with the view on view load

Comment: Yes we want a complete list Please see the The question I'd updated it and added the view that will be binned

Comment: This is what I get after doing that [Just error chnage] (http://prntscr.com/adw0xc)

Comment: Thank you max it was help full